# reinstall without snap but still looking for it

Tags: docker, ubuntu-18.04, snap

I deleted docker with:

```
sudo snap remove docker --purge
```

Then, I install docker following the doc guide ([this](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/))

All looks fine, but when I do:

```
$ docker -v
-bash: /snap/bin/docker: No such file or directory
```

It's like it still look for it in snap.

I tried:

```
$ sudo snap refresh --list
```

But doesn't work. Any idea?

Comment: So you followed the guide. Performed all the steps including `sudo docker run hello-world` and everything looks fine. But when you do `docker -v`, you get an error?

Comment: `sudo docker run hello-world` works, but `docker -v` doesn't

Comment: So root is OK, but the user has some weird settings. Probably an `alias` set in the shell. Try experimenting with https://snapcraft.io/docs/commands-and-aliases ... probably something about `snap unalias`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that the problem is for alias.
try this command `whereis docker`
the output is some thing like this:

```
docker: /usr/bin/docker /etc/docker /usr/libexec/docker /usr/share/man/man1/docker.1.gz
```

now set new alias to docker.

```
alias docker='/usr/bin/docker'
```

try again the problem should be solved.